# Change title (label) of Category Chart - Extjs

Tags: extjs, charts, label

I am having one category chart.
 I want to change title (i.e. label) of category chart on some event.
 How can I get title?
 Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the setTitle method on the Category axis.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Category-method-setTitle